# Possible types of a HTTP header value

Tags: http, http-headers, http2

The type of a value passed through a **query string** is always a string. When a HTTP client need to send a number, let's say `42`, in is actually `"42"`. Everything inside the **query string** is actually a string.

Is it the same for the type of values passed through a **header** ?

In other words, if we send an HTTP request with a `"FooBar"` header with the value of `42`, and another request where the value of the header set to `"42"`, will the server perceive the two received values as of the same type and value (i.e. `"42"`)?

Comment: Was wondering this today!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It's always a string, even in HTTP/2

Comment: Reference? I don't see one. I have tried searching, and your answer comes up, but it is hardly authorative.

Comment: @dsign I tried doing my research, which landed my here. I was just asking if you had a reference, since I failed to find any, and as [I am implicitly responsible for reimplementing parts of the spec](https://github.com/sinonjs/nise/pull/53) I can't just trust some random assertion on the net. But through Wikipedia I was able to find RFC7230. High value answers with all the information one needs is one of the intended goals of SO, so I wasn't trying to offend you :)

Answer (score 11):

**tldr; Headers are text**, sometimes ISO 8859, but usually just US-ASCII.

According to the 2014 [RFC7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.2.4) (last paragraph), HTTP fields have used to be text and new headers should continue to do so, restricting the values to consist of [US-ASCII](http://www.columbia.edu/kermit/ascii.html) octets.

The 1982 [RFC822](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc0822.txt) specifies ASCII as the format of the header body.

References (found through [List of HTTP Headers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#General_format)):

- [Section 3.2 of RFC822](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc0822.txt)
- [RFC7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.2.4)