# Return a boolean from lua nginx module's set_by_lua_block method

Tags: lua, openresty, lua-ngx-module

I'm using [lua nginx module](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module) in my nginx conf file. I'm trying to set a `value` variable during runtime depending on some injected parameters. However, I can not return a boolean from the block without converting it into a string. I'm trying to optimize this part by trying to remove this redundant string conversion.

This one works

```
location /set_by_lua_block_example {
             set_by_lua_block $value {
                return tostring(false)
             }
             
             add_header X-value "$value";

             content_by_lua_block {
                 ngx.say('Printing from set_by_lua_block_example!')
             }
        }
```

But this one doesn't.

```
location /set_by_lua_block_example {
             set_by_lua_block $value {
                return false
             }
             
             add_header X-value "$value";

             content_by_lua_block {
                 ngx.say('Printing from set_by_lua_block_example!')
             }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`set_by_lua`](https://openresty-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Directives/#set_by_lua) family of functions expect string output as per:

> **syntax**: *set_by_lua $res  [$arg1 $arg2 ...]*
>
> Executes code specified in `<lua-script-str>` (...) and returns string output to `$res`.

This applies to [`set_by_lua_block`](https://openresty-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Directives/#set_by_lua_block), too.

Moreover, note that the conversion is not redundant in your case. You use that value later in a HTTP header which [is text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50676124/4567755).

Now, why explicit `tostring(boolean)` is needed? That's because [`lua_tolstring`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#lua_tolstring) is [used to retrieve returned value](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module/blob/974d5d163d86af6852c39143ac6076d0144f79de/src/ngx_http_lua_setby.c#L97). This function (and tostring variant) accepts only strings and numbers.

If you want to store values for use in another Lua block consider using [`ngx.ctx`](https://openresty-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Lua_Nginx_API/#ngxctx).